# Assignment file for VTD's to Congressional Districts? (NYS 2010)

Tags: geospatial, us-census

I'm working with some data at the 2010 Voting Tabulation District level (like the 2010 Census, Vote, and Enrollment data on [this page](http://www.latfor.state.ny.us/data/)).  I'd like to merge in some information about US House districts, and I'm looking for an easy way of seeing which Congressional district each VTD belongs in.  I could grab the district shapefiles and do this with GIS, but worry about it being messy and imperfect.  Is there a relationship file somewhere that maps 2010 New York State VTD's into 2010 NYS Congressional districts?  I'm thinking of something like the Census' [Congressional District Relationship Files](http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cd_state.html), but for VTD's.

Comment: I found some VTD relationship files for NYS, but not exactly the one you are looking for. Perhaps if you dig around this site a little more you might be able to find what you are looking for: http://www.latfor.state.ny.us/data/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get block assignment files for a given state from [this Census Bureau page](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/baf.html)

In those files, there are block assignments for all of the geographies which need to be assigned. You should be able to "join" the VTD and CD tables on common block IDs to get what you need.

Comment: This worked perfectly!  I downloaded the block-to-VTD and block-to-CD assignment files as suggested and was able to use these to bridge the two datasets I had.